# StreamingResponseBody is not working over websocket connecion

Tags: java, spring, websocket, streamingresponsebody

I am trying to stream a video file over an websocket using StreamingResponseBody. But its not working. Is it possible to use StreamingResponseBody over websocket connection?

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class RoomController {

    @Autowired
    RoomService roomService;

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/data")
    public StreamingResponseBody getContent() throws IOException {


        // Replace with the path to your video file
        Path videoPath = Paths.get("F:\\earth.mp4");

        // Open the video file as an InputStream
        InputStream videoInputStream = Files.newInputStream(videoPath, StandardOpenOption.READ);

        // Create an InputStreamSource from the InputStream
        InputStreamSource source = new InputStreamResource(videoInputStream);

        return outputStream -> {
            log.warn("inside writeTo");  //<- not logging on console
            InputStream is = source.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                log.warn("Read byte {}", bytesRead);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        };

    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*its not working*"?

Comment: i mean their is no data at client end.